# Common file system API for files in the cloud?

Tags: filesystems, cloud, webdav, sftp

Our app is a sort-of self-service website builder for a particular industry. We need to be able to store the HTML and image files for each customer's site so that users can easily access and edit them. I'd really like to be able to store the files on S3, but potentially other places like Box.net, Google Docs, Dropbox, and Rackspace Cloud Files.

It would be easiest if there there some common file system API that I could use over these repositories, but unfortunately everything is proprietary. So I've got to implement something. FTP or SFTP is the obvious choice, but it's a lot of work. WebDAV will also be a pain.

Our server-side code is Java.

Please someone give me a magic solution which is fast, easy, standards-based, and will solve all my problems perfectly without any effort on my part. Please?

Comment: "Please someone give me a magic solution which is fast, easy, standards-based, and will solve all my problems perfectly without any effort on my part. Please?" - If you find this, form a company to sell it. You'll make billions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but we built http://mover.io to address this kind of thing. We currently support 13 different end points and we have a GUI interface and an API for interfacing with all these cloud storage providers.

Comment: Now that mover was bought by microsoft (2019), I'm not sure this solution applies anymore.

Comment: Totally, good point. Mover ended support for the API quite a long time ago, before being acquired.